# <p:commandButton> doesn't work inside of p:dataGrid when column = 4 row = 1

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datagrid, commandbutton

I just want to add p:commandButton for each item in list in p:dataGrid.

> But, when I set columns = 4 and rows = 1 from properties p:dataGrid. I can't get value from commandButton anymore in rest of list (except for the first item in list).

Tried change into h:commandButton, p:commandLink, ajax= false;

```java
<p:dataGrid var="list" value="#{myBean.listCompany}" columns="4" layout="grid"rows="1" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" paginatorTemplate="{PreviousPageLink} {NextPageLink} ">
                                        
<div class="card" style="height: 350px">
  <p:column>    
     <p:panel>
         <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <p:commandButton value="Choose" action="#{myBean.selectCompany(list.companyName)}">
        </p:commandButton>
      </h:panelGrid> 
      </p:panel> 
     </p:column>
  </div>
</p:dataGrid>
```

> Based on this , https://knowles.co.za/primefaces-actions-not-firing-in-last-rows-of-datagrid/
>
> The quick fix is just to set the number of rows correctly, to fill the number of columns you have. As long as the number of rows is a multiple of the number of columns (eg, 2 columns, 6 rows) you should be fine.

But, this is not the solution that I want, I need to display p:dataGrid with 4 columns and 1 row.

Comment: You don't need `h:panelGrid columns="1"` and probably and `p:panel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your intention right that you want to display 4 elements out of `#{myBean.listCompany}` in one row, you should set `colums="4"` and `rows="4"`.

This way `rows` is a multiple of the number of `columns` with the multiplicator being `1`.

Rows here seemes to be the total number of elements from `#{myBean.listCompany}` to display per page. If this does not match with a multiple of columns, there seemes to be some kind of mismatch between rendering and component input handling.

You can add a `rowIndexVar="rowIndex"` and output that with each element to make visible what one row is in a dataGrid.

```
<p:dataGrid var="list" value="#{myBean.listCompany}" columns="4"
    layout="grid" rows="4" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
    paginatorTemplate="{PreviousPageLink} {NextPageLink} " rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

    <div class="card" style="height: 350px">
        <p:column>
            <p:panel>
                <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <p:commandButton value="Choose Row #{rowIndex}"
                        action="#{myBean.selectCompany(list.companyName)}">
                    </p:commandButton>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </p:column>
    </div>
</p:dataGrid>
```